# How to call Base contract function externally when only Derived contract deployed

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-contract

**Base**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract ZombieFactory {

    event NewZombie(uint zombieId, string name, uint dna);

    uint dnaDigits = 16;
    uint dnaModulus = 10 ** dnaDigits;

    struct Zombie {
        string name;
        uint dna;
    }

    Zombie[] public zombies;

    mapping (uint => address) public zombieToOwner;
    mapping (address => uint) ownerZombieCount;

    function _createZombie(string _name, uint _dna) internal {
        uint id = zombies.push(Zombie(_name, _dna)) - 1;
        zombieToOwner[id] = msg.sender;
        ownerZombieCount[msg.sender]++;
        NewZombie(id, _name, _dna);
    }

    function _generateRandomDna(string _str) private view returns (uint) {
        uint rand = uint(keccak256(_str));
        return rand % dnaModulus;
    }

    function createRandomZombie(string _name) public {
        require(ownerZombieCount[msg.sender] == 0);
        uint randDna = _generateRandomDna(_name);
        randDna = randDna - randDna % 100;
        _createZombie(_name, randDna);
    }

    function getZombieDnaById(uint _id) public view returns (uint) {
        return zombies[_id].dna;
    }

    function getZombieCount() public pure returns (uint) {
        //return ownerZombieCount[msg.sender];
        return 6789;
    }

}
```

**Derived**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

import "./ZombieFactory.sol";

contract KittyInterface {
  function getKitty(uint256 _id) external view returns (
    bool isGestating,
    bool isReady,
    uint256 cooldownIndex,
    uint256 nextActionAt,
    uint256 siringWithId,
    uint256 birthTime,
    uint256 matronId,
    uint256 sireId,
    uint256 generation,
    uint256 genes
  );
}

contract ZombieFeeding is ZombieFactory {

  address ckAddress = 0x06012c8cf97BEaD5deAe237070F9587f8E7A266d;
  KittyInterface kittyContract = KittyInterface(ckAddress);

  // Modify function definition here:
  function feedAndMultiply(uint _zombieId, uint _targetDna) public {
    require(msg.sender == zombieToOwner[_zombieId]);
    Zombie storage myZombie = zombies[_zombieId];
    _targetDna = _targetDna % dnaModulus;
    uint newDna = (myZombie.dna + _targetDna) / 2;
    // Add an if statement here
    _createZombie("NoName", newDna);
  }

  function feedOnKitty(uint _zombieId, uint _kittyId) public {
    uint kittyDna;
    (,,,,,,,,,kittyDna) = kittyContract.getKitty(_kittyId);
    // And modify function call here:
    feedAndMultiply(_zombieId, kittyDna);
  }
}
```

2_deploy_contracts.js

```
var ZombieFeeding = artifacts.require("./ZombieFeeding.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(ZombieFeeding);
};
```

app.js

```
CryptoZombiesFeeding.deployed().then(function(contractInstance){

  console.log(contractInstance);

  // call getZombieCount() of Base contract ZombieFactory.sol
  contractInstance.getZombieCount.call().then(function(zombieCount){
    console.log("address " + account + " has " + zombieCount + " zombies");
  });      

});
```

Commands

`truffle migrate --reset`

Everything builds ok, the contract `ZombieFeeding` is migrated successfully, and the contents of the contract instance in the client application contains both the parent and derived function references.

[image]

The problem is that when I call the `getZombieCount` function it returns `0`, and it should be `6789`. If I deploy the `ZombieFactory` contract alongside the `ZombieFeeding` contract it works. This shows me that when I use inheritance, the parent contracts functions can't be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

When calling the contract add a `from:address` parameter to create a `transaction`. Transactions require `gas` and are needed to store data or run computations on contracts.

Example

**app.js**

```
// call Base contract function with transaction
CryptoZombiesFeeding.deployed().then(function(contractInstance){
  contractInstance.createRandomZombie(username, {from: address}).then(function(response){
    console.log("random zombie created with dna " + response);
  });
});
```

EDIT: The `address` is your Ether wallet address that is available through the web3 library.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the problem is the way you call the function, but if you are using web3j library, the correct way to call the function is:

```
contractInstance.methods.getZombieCount().call()
```

If you are using ethers library:

```
contractInstance.getZombieCount()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this to the migration file:

```
var ZombieFactory= artifacts.require("./ZombieFactory.sol");
var KittyInterface = artifacts.require("./KittyInterface.sol");
var ZombieFeeding = artifacts.require("./ZombieFeeding.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
deployer.deploy(KittyInterface );
deployer.deploy(ZombieFactory);
deployer.link(ZombieFactory,ZombieFeeding);
deployer.deploy(ZombieFeeding);
};
```

Comment: So yes this works as mentioned in the question if I deploy both the Parent and Derived contracts, but you should only need to deploy the derived contract, the compilation stage concatenates the parent and derived before deploying.

Comment: Inheritance in the docs http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#inheritance `When a contract inherits from multiple contracts, only a single contract is created on the blockchain, and the code from all the base contracts is copied into the created contract.`

Comment: You do not have to deploy base classes ZombieFactory nor the interface contract KittyInterface.